# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline with custom settings.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins **Declarative Pipeline** with maven.  So far I can get maven to run, but I can't get it to use my defined Maven Settings.xml.

```
pipeline{
   agent any
   tools{
       maven 'Apache Maven 3.3'
       // without mavenSettingsConfig, my settings.xml is not used.  With it, this blows up
       mavenSettingsConfig: 'Global Maven Settings'
       jdk 'jdk9
   }
   stages {
       stage('Preparation'){
           steps{
              //code checkout stuff here--this works fine
           }
       }
       stage('Build'){
            steps{
               sh "mvn clean install -P foo"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

The problem seems to be mavenSettingsConfig.  Without that property, I can't figure out how to set the settings.xml, and my custom maven stuff doesn't work.  (Profile foo, for example.) With the mavenSettingsConfig, it blows up:

BUG!  exception in phase 'canonicalization' in source unit 'WorkflowScript' unexpected NullpointerException....

The documentation has a big TODO in it where it would provide an example for this!  So how do I do it?

(Documentation TODO at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin.  It actually says "TODO provide a sample with Jenkins Declarative Pipeline")

Answer (score 28, accepted):

my advice is to use the Config File Provider plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

With it, you define your config file once in Jenkins' "Config File Management" screen and then have code like this in your pipeline:

```
stage('Build'){
    steps{
       configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'my-maven-settings-dot-xml', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML')]) {
            sh 'mvn -U --batch-mode -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML clean install -P foo'
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The advantage of using the Config File Provider plugin is that you can then easily add new Jenkins slaves without having to pre-configure existing files on them (such as your settings.xml file): each job can be executed anywhere with no configuration because everything is in Jenkins and provided at runtime.

Comment: This works, but not using the name you give to the config file. I needed to use the internal id (Which you can get if you let the pipeline generator generate the config for the pipeline)

Comment: Follow-up to my comment: You need to set the id when creating the configFile setting, then you can have something reable like `mvn-settings-artifactory` instead of something like `372201c4-12a6-4846-ab43-664815c21d4e`.

Comment: Can this be extracted to a def function? Otherwise I need those lines for each maven call, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Hervian I thinks so with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081177/259988 - but I'm not sure it is worth the pain as sometimes it's good to be explicit and simple even at the cost of a few characters...
my 2 cents

Comment: @FrancoisMarot How I can use Jenkins variable with config file provider? I need to pass ${workspace} to get path of  working Dir

Answer (score 9):

you have to declare and maven installation in your jenkins 
`Managed Jenkins > Global Tools configuration` and add maven installation named like M3.

[declare a maven installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rhy4.png)

After you have to registry your settings file :

```
manage jenkins > Managed files
```

And add your setting File

After this you can use the WithMaven function with your registry file like this:

```
steps {
    withMaven(maven: 'M3', mavenSettingsConfig: 'mvn-setting-xml') {
        sh "mvn clean install "
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: The withMaven step is only available if you have the necessary plugin installed.

Answer (score 3):

Also possible, to use the secret file credentials from [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin)

Create a secret file in jenkins:
[image]

Then you can use this settings file like this

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        MVN_SET = credentials('maven_settings')
    }
    agent {
        docker 'maven:3-alpine'
    }
    stages {
        stage('mvn test settings') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -s $MVN_SET help:effective-settings'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashed, because it resolved to
mvn clean install -B -e -q -T4C -Pstaging,fastest -s @configFile(fileId=229e62cb-3b3e-4ccc-870d-dee6c2769b9d,replaceTokens=true,targetLocation=settings.xml,variable=M2_SETTINGS)

Comment: It was because I had the groovy header at the top of the Jenkinsfile. When I removed it it works! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue all you have to do is add this small piece of code in your line

```
def mvnSettings = 'Location of the file'
sh "mvn clean install --settings ${mvnSettings} -P foo"
```

So now whenever maven runs it will locate the settings.xml file in the PATH that you specified

P.S. its a maven command which you can use to run on command Line

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I choose this solution except that the definition is out of the pipeline brackets  </br> def mvnSettings = 'mvnSettings.xml'  </br>    pipeline {  </br>   ....  </br>  }

Answer (score 2):

Combining the accepted answer of @Francois Marot and the link provided by the OP, we get:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                withMaven() {
                    bat 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses both the "Managed Files" plugin and the "Global Tool Configuration" plugin (Maven configuration, Maven installation, JDK installation) to specify the settings.xml file implicitly.