# Scripted pipeline: wrap stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to be able to wrap a 'stage' in Jenkins, so I can execute custom code at the start and end of a stage, so something like:

```
myStage('foo') {
}
```

I thought I could do this by using metaClass:

```
           //Wrap stages to automatically trace
           def originalMethod = this.metaClass.getMetaMethod("stage", null)
           this.metaClass.myStage = { args ->
                   println "Beginning of stage"
                   println "Args: " + args
                   def result = originalMethod.invoke(delegate, args)
                   println "End of stage"
                   return result
           }
```

But it appears the Groovy script itself is a Binding, which doesn't have a metaClass:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: metaClass for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I'm still learning how Groovy and Jenkins Pipeline work, so perhaps I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with the metaclass concept but I think that a simple solution to your problem is to define a wrapped stage as a function. 
Here's an example of how you'd define such a function:

```
def wrappedStage(name, Closure closure) {
    stage(name) {
        echo "Beginning of stage"
        def result = closure.call()
        echo "End of stage"
        return result
    }
}
```

and this is how you would call it:

```
wrappedStage('myStage') {
    echo 'hi'
}
```

The return value of `wrappedStage` would only make sense when the body of your stage actually returns something, for example:

1. If you call another job, eg:

   ```
   wrappedStage('myStage') {
       build job: 'myJob'
   }
   ```

   you will get back `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper` which you can use to access info of the job you run, like result, variables etc
2. If you print something to the console, eg:

   ```
   wrappedStage('myStage') {
       echo 'hi'
   }
   ```

   you will get back `null`.

Note that in my example I am not printing args because the way I understand `stage`, it only takes 2 arguments; the stage name and the closure it should run. The name of the stage will already be printed in the log, and I don't know how much value you'd get from printing the code you're about to execute but if that's something you want to do, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5279211/9498358).

If you have a more specific case in mind for what you'd want to wrap, you can add more params to the wrapper and print all the information you want through those extra parameters.